# C++ BucketList class initalization

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have been given an assignment related to Linked List Data Structure. I'm having trouble getting started. I just need help initializing the constructor.

BucketList.h

```
#ifndef BUCKETLIST_H_
#define BUCKETLIST_H_

#include <string>
using std::string;

class Node {
    // Data members. Do not change them
    string s_; // string stored in this node
    Node* next_; // pointer to next node in the list

    // even constructors are private!
    // so only BucketList can access them
    Node();
    ~Node();

    // You can add other member functions if you want

friend class BucketList; // allow BucketList to access private members
};

class BucketList {

public:
    // Constructor. Constructs an empty BucketList with initial capacity
    // INITIAL_CAP with no contents.
    BucketList();

    // Destructor. Deallocate all memory used.
    ~BucketList();

    // Copy constructor.
    BucketList(const BucketList& other);

    // Copy assignment operator.
    BucketList& operator=(const BucketList& other);

    // Return true if the string s is in the BucketList, false otherwise.
    bool contains(const string& s) const;

    // Insert the string s into the BucketList.
    // If s is already in the BucketList, do not change anything.
    // If the bucket is going to contain more than one string
    // (i.e. the list has more than one node), they should be ordered
    // alphabetically (i.e. based on how C++ compares strings)
    // If the load factor is going to be exceeded after the insertion
    // (i.e. number of strings / capacity of container > MAX_LOAD_FACTOR),
    // double the capacity of the container first before the insertion.
    // See the assignment webpage for details on doubling.
    void insert(const string& s);

    // Remove the string s from the BucketList.
    // If s is not in the BucketList, do not change anything.
    void remove(const string& s);

    // Return a string representation of the BucketList, as described
    // in the assignment webpage.
    // Note that it does not actually print anything to the screen.
    // To pass the test cases you must make sure that even the
    // white spaces are correct. In particular,
    // there should be no space character after the number if no string is in 
    // that bucket; no space character after the last string of a bucket;
    // and no newline character after the last line.
    string toString() const;

    // The mash function that converts the string s to an integer.
    // This really shouldn't be public, but it is for the purpose of
    // testing.
    int h(const string& s) const;

    // Return the number of strings currently stored in the BucketList.
    int getSize() const;

    // Return the capacity (i.e. size of the array, or number of buckets)
    // of the BucketList.
    int getCap() const;

    // we didn't explain what static and constexpr are, but you can just
    // use them like normal constants in BucketList.cpp
    static constexpr int INITIAL_CAP = 10; // initial capacity
    static constexpr double MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.7; // maximum load factor

private:

    Node** buckets_; // pointer to an array of Node*

    // You can add any other private member variables or functions
    // if you want

};

#endif /* BUCKETLIST_H_ */
```

BucketList.cpp

```
#include "BucketList.h"

Node::Node() {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}

Node::~Node() {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}

BucketList::BucketList() {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}

BucketList::~BucketList() {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}

BucketList::BucketList(const BucketList& other) {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}

BucketList& BucketList::operator=(const BucketList& other) {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
    return *this;
}

bool BucketList::contains(const string& s) const {

    // THIS IS DONE FOR YOU AS AN EXAMPLE
    // but you need to change something...

    int hc = h(s) % INITIAL_CAP; // ...here.
    Node* temp = buckets_[hc];
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        if (temp->s_ == s) return true;
        temp = temp->next_;
    }
    return false;
}

void BucketList::insert(const string& s) {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}

void BucketList::remove(const string& s) {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}

string BucketList::toString() const {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
    return ""; // dummy
}

int BucketList::h(const string& s) const {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
    return -1; // dummy
}

int BucketList::getSize() const {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
    return -1; // dummy
}

int BucketList::getCap() const {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
    return -1; // dummy
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BucketList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    BucketList t;
    t.insert("a");
    t.insert("cac");
    t.insert("abc");

    cout << t.contains("a") << endl;
    cout << t.contains("abc") << endl;
    cout << t.contains("cac") << endl;
    cout << t.contains("d") << endl << endl;

    cout << t.toString() << endl << endl;

    t.remove("a");
    cout << t.toString() << endl << endl;

    t.remove("abc");
    cout << t.toString() << endl << endl;

    BucketList t2;
    t2 = t;
    cout << t2.toString() << endl;

}
```

I don't want anyone to implement all of these. I just need a small favour in understanding the constructor initialization in bucketList.cpp

Can anybody tell me how I can initialize the constructor of Node class and BucketList class?

Comment: i think you have already the constructor and you need to impelement it, implement the behaviour of constructing the class.

Comment: Yes, i need help with `BucketList::BucketList() {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
}` this implementation

Comment: but what help you need? i'm sorry i didin't get it